# Function returning itself, unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript

Expected behavior is to add from multiple invocations, until the empty invocation is reached, but that's not what the code does. What's actually going on?

```js
function addg(first) {
  function more(next) {
    if (next === undefined) {
      return first;
    }
    first += next;
    return more;
  }
  if (first !== undefined) {
    return more;
  }
}

// expected behavior:
console.log( addg(3)(2)(4)() ); // 9
```

Comment: Can you show how this is intended to be used?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what is is that you're wanting to do. Your addg function is simply returning the more function reference.

Comment: It's returning the function, but not calling it. The `more` function is never executed

Comment: @blex I suspect it's intended to be called by the caller, e.g. `addg(5)()`

Comment: You have to use parentheses to invoke the function.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking; it sounds like you understand what this does, and running the function does what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: It did not work like that in the browser console, I honestly don't know what happened @Jacob

Comment: Seems to me that you want to do somethings similar to curryN as desscribed here in the ramda docs https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curryN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a clever way to enable:

```
addg(1)(2)(3)(4)() // 10;
```

The `return more` line returns a function; the inner body of the function references the `first` variable, which is to say it "closes over" that variable. That's how when you call the returned function, it knows about the value of `first` and can add to it. The `more` function can also return itself, so each time you call `addg` (until you pass undefined or omit the parameter), it returns a function which can be called again.

(note that this is not necessarily the best approach to the problem, but it does demonstrate that you can return functions from a function).

Comment:  And it's called a "curried function"

Comment: Weird. I tried all day in the browser console and it did not produce that behavior. Works like a charm now. I suppose thread can be closed/deleted since there was nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your curried `addg` function to take an arbitrary number of arguments before the final result function call e.g.:

```js
function addg(...args) {
  return (...more) => {
    if (more.length === 0) {
      return args.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
    }

    return addg.apply(addg, args.concat(more)) 
  }
}

console.log(addg(2)(3)(4)()) // => 9
console.log(addg(2, 3)(4)()) // => 9
console.log(addg(2, 3, 4)()) // => 9
```

---

1. Eric Elliot has a nice article about [Curry and Function
   Composition](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983)
2. I can recommend the [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) library if you are
   writing a larger application where you want to leverage a functional
   approach.